# Font for formula reverts to 10 not matter what font size the cell is set to

Tags: google-sheets

I making videos about using spreadsheets for my elementary age students.  I want the font to be as large as possible.  So I set the font for a cell to 18, for example.

[image: before adding the = sign, a nice, big font]

But once I put the = sign in, it becomes a formula and reverts back to font size 10 which is hard for my students to see.

[image]

Has anyone else noticed this? Is there something simple I can do so that forumulas come out the same size as the font for the cell so my videos will work better.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to zoom the browser?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the default behavior in Google Sheets, unfortunately. To make it easy for your students to see the formulas:

1. Make the font size for the whole sheet 10pt.
2. Increase the magnification on your browser.  (Ctrl-mouse-wheel on a PC, and probably Cmd-mouse-wheel on a Mac.)